# Does iOS 6 turn-by-turn navigation work with satellite images?

Tags: maps, navigation, ios

Without modifications, can a user turn on satellite images for iOS 6 turn-by-turn navigation use satellite images rather than just a simple interface and monochrome 3D buildings—although it may be distracting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't seem to be possible.  If you are in satellite mode, it switches back to "standard" when you start the navigation.  It's a shame, that would be pretty cool.

Comment: Thanks. Won't be getting iOS 6 until Christmas, so it's good to know.